# How to show that a function satisfying certain inequalities exist?

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of Natural numbers, and let $b,s\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $1\leq b\leq s-3$. I want to know whether there exists a Real-valued function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
\begin{gather}
f(s)>0\\
f(s)>f(s+1)\\
(s-b)\cdot f(s)>(t-b)\cdot f(t)\quad\forall t\text{ s.t. }t\geq b+2\text{ and }t<s
\end{gather}

I have tried to construct one such function, but I haven't succeeded, as all of them have failed the third condition. Then, I have tried to prove that one such function does not exist, but I haven't succeeded. I do not need any specific function, I simply need an argument (constructive or otherwise) that establishes the existence of one such function.

Comment: Define $f'(s)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Here, $f’(s)$ is the derivative of $f$.

Comment: From your first sentence, it looks like $s$ is fixed. But in the requirements, you have "$\forall s\geqslant 4$".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Here, $s$ is not fixed: it can be anything bigger or equal than $b+3$.

Comment: Derivative is not defined for functions with domain $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By $f’(s)<0$, I just wanted to say that if $t>s$, then $f(t)<f(s)$. I suppose I have (wrongly) abused language. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n)=1/n$ for natural $n$.

Certainly $f(s)>0$, and certainly $f(s)=1/s>1/(s+1)=f(s+1)$.
$$
(s-b)f(s)={s-b\over s}=1-{b\over s}
$$
For $s>t$ we have $1/s<1/t$ so $-1/s>-1/t$. Hence,
$$
1-{b\over s}>1-{b\over t}={t-b\over t}=(t-b)f(t)
$$
and we win.